# Find Longitude Latitude in Large File

Tags: export, large-data

I would like to know if there is a quick way of doing this.

I have a data file with over 700,000 rows. The data file gives me the attributes Country, City, and Address. I need to use this data set on a Map report. My problem is the tool needs Longitude and Latitude attributes.

My file doesn't have Longitude or Latitude. Is there a way for me to get the Longitude and Latitude for the entire data set using the current attributes without having to look up the addresses one by one on google?